# Add a resource reference in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

Is it possible in XAML to add a reference to resource? For example I have
`<Color x:Key="LightRed">#e24c3f</Color>`
and I need to have something like
`<Color x:Key="ErrorColor">*LightRed*</Color>`.

Comment: If you have `<Color x:Key="LightRed">#e24c3f</Color>` and you want to reference it somewhere else, like in a SolidColorBrush, you would do like this:  `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ErrorBrush" Color="{StaticResource LightRed}"/>`

Comment: You may want to have two SolidColorBrush resources that use the same Color resource for their Color property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a `Color` resource cannot reference another `Color` resource if that's what you are asking.

As suggested by @Nawed Nabi Zada, you may define a *brush* that uses any color resource though:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ErrorBrush" Color="{StaticResource LightRed}"/>
```

You can easily change the colour of the brush in one place.